# Laravel php artisan db:seed leads to "use" statement error

Tags: php

When I try to run `php artisan db:seed` I get the following error:

`The use statement with non-compound name 'DB' has no effect`

I have written my own seeder file which I have included below, based on a [snippet from the doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding#writing-seeders). As you can see I am using the `use DB` shortcut - is this what the problem is?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class ClassesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('classes')->delete();
        DB::table('classes')->insert([
            'class_name'    => 'Test course 111',
            'class_id'      => '1',
            'location_name' => 'Barnes',
            'location_id'   => '1',
            'date'          => '2015-06-22',
            'month'         => '06/2015',
            'start_time'    => '08:00',
            'end_time'      => '16:00',
            'places'        => '19',
            'places_left'   => '19',
            'price'         => '155.00'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In PHP the **use** statement is more of an **alias** than import. So since the **ClassesTableSeeder** class isn't in a defined namespace, you don't need to import the DB class. As a result you can remove **use DB** entirely.

Comment: Why is it that the Laravel Docs have use DB? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding#writing-seeders

Comment: Probably just a glitch in the docs. You certainly don't need to import anything if you're not using a namespace.

Answer (score 6):

use the following instead of `use DB`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it, especially if a question already holds some old and highly upvoted answer

Answer (score 2):

In seeder class You don't need to `use DB` statement on top of the page. Any alias written inside `config>app.php` aliases array don't require `use` statement. This is because seeder doesn't have any namespace.

Answer (score 2):

in laravel migration you dont need call DB ;

remove `use DB;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following instead of `use DB`.

```
use DB as DBS;
```

After that, you can use it as follows.

```
DBS::table('foo')->insert([
            'name'=>'bar',
        ]);
```