# Error while loading Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel framework and after trying to start an application I am receiving this error with this stacktrace:

```
[2015-12-16 10:29:20] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'The use statement with non-compound name 'DB' has no effect' in /Users/username/data/product/app/controllers/CampaignsController.php:3
```

This is how the Controller looks like in the beginning:

```
<?php

use \DB;
use \Auth;
use \Validator;
use \Event;
........
```

What am I missing here? Is it because i need to install some plugin for Laravel to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088292/laravel-php-artisan-dbseed-leads-to-use-statement-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not located within the namespace, so you can not execute `use` statements.

For example, if you're in a controller you might want to add following namespace at the top of the file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \DB;
...
```

Comment: It started to complain about not finding other classes not within the folder.

Comment: @Leon, Laravel-specific classes or your own classes? When you jintroduce namespaces you have to explicitly add additional classes which are out of the namespace scope with `use` statements.

Check following video explaining some of the basics of namespaces: https://laracasts.com/lessons/namespacing-primer